# "Checked shirt" vs "check shirt"

Tags: word-choice, american-english, british-english

My son is learning English as a foreign language and I notice a mixture of British and American words in his vocab lists. Is there such thing as a *checked shirt*, or should it be a *check shirt*?

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking about this kind of [pattern](http://girlnextdoorfashion.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/55701_lg1.jpg), I believe "checkered" would be correct.

Depending on the exact pattern, though, "[plaid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaid_%28pattern%29)" may be a better word.

Comment: What?  The predominant term in American English, at least according to [Google Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/ngrams/graph?content=checked+shirt%2C+checkered+shirt%2C+check+shirt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) is "checked shirt" (what I'd use), with "checkered shirt" and "check shirt" both around half the frequency.

Comment: In the northeast US, I agree that "checked shirt" would be most common for alternating colored blocks of approximately the same size ([like this](http://www4.images.coolspotters.com/photos/103968/red-checkered-shirt-profile.jpg)), although "checkered shirt" is not uncommon. "Check shirt" would be understandable, but rare.  The shirt pictured in the above answer would commonly be described as plaid, but I agree that *checkered* would be acceptable.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen "check shirt" or "checked shirt" used in this context. I assumed it was just a British English thing.

Comment: *Check* is the name of the pattern, so you would say "checked shirt" like *stripe* = "striped shirt."

Comment: I rescind my edit saying it is unused in American English.

Comment: A *checkered shirt* (or *checkered tablecloth*) brings to mind something that has just two colors/shades such as a red and white *checkered* tablecloth - very cliche in countrified picnic ware. *Plaid* brings to mind something that has at least three colors with lines of different widths - more in line with a tartan as mentioned above. (This is my personal connotation - nothing sourced here.)

Comment: Surely checkered is a corruption of 'chequered', as in 'a chequered past'? (Am going to check this.....)

Answer (score 4):

*Check shirt* would be normal in British English. A *checked shirt* suggests one that has been inspected and found to be satisfactory.

Comment: Depending on your sense of style, the two may never be the same.

Comment: [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=checked+shirt%2Ccheckered+shirt%2Ccheck+shirt%2Cchequered+shirt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) says that "checked shirt" and "check shirt" are used nearly equally often in the U.K. Of course, it's possible they are both pronounced "check shirt".

Comment: Yes. Any difference would be barely noticeable.

Comment: I can't say that it inspires confidence that the first few results for "check shirt" (British English) are obviously American sources. OTOH BNC also has them equal (12 hits each). (Surprising to me: "check shirt" as a noun isn't in my idiolect).

Comment: @Peter: Google books Ngram actually doesn't separate British and American sources when you check the results (although they separate them in the Ngram). I hope they eventually get around to fixing this. Re: "check shirt" not being in your idiolect, I would have said that "check shirt" is a spelling pronunciation for "checked shirt", except for the fact that Google Ngrams shows they both been quite common since people started using either term circa 1800.

Answer (score 4):

The Corpus of Contemporary American English shows that *plaid* is much more common in American English (more than 3x) than the variants of *checked* combined. (The following numbers are for collocates with *shirt*, for example, *plaid shirt*.)

```
plaid       213
check       6
checked     34
checkered   23
```

It seems *checked shirt* may be slightly more common than *check* or *checkered* in the US.

The British National Corpus does not seem to have many instances referencing these patterns, but it does suggest that the *checked shirt* and *check shirt* variants are more common in British English than *plaid*.

```
plaid       4
check       12
checked     12
checkered   0
```

This doesn't mean that there's no difference between *plaid* and *checked* for anyone, but as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaid) suggests,

> Plaid (pattern) is also used as a synonym for tartan or, in the USA, any checked cloth pattern.

In summary, for American English, you might want to avoid the question entirely and substitute the much more common *plaid*. For British English, or to be understood internationally, *checked* is likely a good way to describe this type of pattern (and as @Peter Shor notes, *check shirt* and *checked shirt* will not be easily distinguishable in speech in any case).